# What does this apache redirect mean?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.safepub.com/home [r=301,nc,L]
```

How do I rewrite this rule so that safepub.com isn't redirected to safepub.com/home?

Thanks.